# How to match all documents where all values exist in an array filled of embedded document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection `Users`:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda04"), 
    "username": "user1", 
    "roles": [
                {"_id" : ObjectId("3aded105e90424e1c0e6fb542"), "name":"admin"},
                {"_id" : ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05"), "name": "fin"},
            ]
},
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05"), 
    "username": "user2", 
    "roles": [
                {"_id" : ObjectId("3aded105e90424e1c0e6fb542"), "name":"admin"},
                {"_id" : ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05"), "name":"fin"},
            ]
},
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda06"), 
    "username": "user3", 
    "roles": [
                {"_id" : ObjectId("9bded105e45624e1c0e6fb289"), "name":"basic"},
                {"_id" : ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05"), "name": "fin"},
            ]
}
```

I am trying to match all documents from Users that the roles field contain all the elements in array `arr = [ObjectId("3aded105e90424e1c0e6fb542"), ObjectId("5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05")]`, i.e. I want to write a query using mongodb c# driver to match all documents if the roles field contain all the requested roles ex: 'admin' and 'fin'.

The result should be user1 and user2

Note: it is easy to be done if the `roles` is not an array of embedded documents by using `.All` operator:

```
filter &= Builders<Users>.Filter.All(
                    doc => doc.Roles,
                    Ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining filters solves your problem, however I have no idea about performance.

```
var roleIdList = new List<string>
                 {
                     "3aded105e90424e1c0e6fb542",
                     "5ded105e90424e1c0e6fda05"
                 };


foreach (string roleId in roleIdList)
{
    filter &= Builders<User>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Roles, x => x.Id == roleId);
}
```